# INSERT through SphinxSE

Tags: sphinx, mariadb

I defined a real-time index (RT index) on SphinxSearch 2.1.8:

```
index rt
{
    type = rt
    path = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/rt
    rt_field = url
}
```

Then I declared a table in MariaDB 10.0.11 using SPHINX Storage Engine:

```
CREATE TABLE `rt` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `weight` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `query` text NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `query` (`query`(1024))
) ENGINE=SPHINX DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 CONNECTION='sphinx://127.0.0.1:9312/rt';
```

**Is it possible to INSERT data into my RT index through the SphinxSE table ?**

When I try to insert, I have this error:

```
MariaDB [mydb]> INSERT INTO rt(id, url) VALUES (1, 'http://www.stackoverflow.com');
ERROR 1031 (HY000): Storage engine SPHINX of the table `mydb`.`rt` doesn't have this option
```

According to [this comment from MariaDB KB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sphinxse-does-the-sphinx-storage-engine-support-rt-indexes-can-you-write-to/) it may be possible to INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE a rt index through SphinxSE, but I wonder how...

> While in theory it's now possible to have it proxy INSERTs, DELETEs
>   and other writes to Sphinx, it was never initially designed for this,
>   so that change could be cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That comment is says it theory possible to modify the **source code** of the SphinxSE engine, to enable such updates. Basically it will instead make a SphinxQL connect to sphinx, and issue appropriate commands.

But as noted it wasnt designed for that (for example it takes a SphinxAPI port in the table definition - so would need to find another way to tell the engine the SphinxQL port to use) - it will be kind of difficult to do.

... so not possible now. But could be possible if someone wrote the code to do so.

Probably much easier to modify your application to talk SphinxQL directly to Sphinx.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification. In fact, my goal was to update rt-index using mysql triggers. I have to find another solution.

Comment: In theory can use the Connect engine. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connect-table-types-mysql-table-type-accessing-mysqlmariadb-tables/ It proxies though to an underlying mysql table, as a sphinxql index looks 'like' a mysql table, it might well work.